# PHP SOAP call aborting connection

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

the following php soap call:

```
$retVal = parent::__soapCall($function_name, $arguments, $options, $input_headers, $output_headers);
```

with variables as follow:

```
 1. $function_name = "query"
 2. $arguments = Array ( [0] => Array ( [store] => Array ( [scheme] => workspace [address] => SpacesStore ) [query] => Array ( [language] => lucene [statement] => PATH:"app:company_home" ) [includeMetaData] => ) )
 3. $options = Array ( )
 4. $input_headers = Array ( [0] => SoapHeader Object ( [namespace] => http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd [name] => Security [data] => [mustUnderstand] => 1 ) ) 
 5. $output_headers = Array ( )
```

is not working and is causing connection to abort. Of course I can't get `$retVal` content because script execution stops on `__soapCall`.
I'm not expert of `SOAP`. I don't even know if it is lacking some lib (it didn't working at all so far, new server installation): open-ssl, curl and soap extensions are all installed and enabled.

Is there someone that could give some advice on why the script should crash instead of providing some video error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is I was missing a php extension causing the call to die.

Missing class was DOMdocument and to install it was pretty easy (not as it was to detect it):

```
yum -y install lib-xml
service httpd restart
```

missing lib obtained, all worked.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably this is [SoapClient::__soapCall](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php)

Is there anything appearing in any error logs?

Try using the following functions to look for clues:

1. [__getLastRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) (Use that to check that the XML looks correct)
2. [__getLastRequestHeaders](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequestheaders.php) (As Above)
3. [__getLastResponse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php) (Sounds like this will probably be empty but worth a shot)
4. [__getLastResponseHeaders](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponseheaders.php) (As above)